# Being Reimbursed for Personal Property Used for Business

Tags: company-policy, compensation

So, when I started a new job, I used my personal laptop for work purposes (because the computers there were full of spam and unsecure). Eventually, the work software caused my laptop to crash. My owner agreed to buy me a new one (because my old one was no longer useable). I purchased the machine in a credit line under my name, but paid the credit line through the business. The laptop is also registered to me personally.

My owner is a jerk (surprise, surprise) and is now claiming that he can take my laptop whenever he wants and that I should watch out, because I am a student and I am lucky he lets me use it for school.

Can he legally take this from me, and if so, how can I make this not the case (do I need to pay for it, part of it...?). I would like to not have to pay for it because it was meant to replace my personal property destroyed while being utilized for company purposes.

Comment: "My owner agreed to buy me a new one" - what form of agreement was this, verbal or written? Was it in the form of "I'll buy **you** a new laptop", or was it "I'll buy **a** new laptop"? Unless you have some sort of proof that he was offering to replace your personal property with company funds, then to an unbiased outsider it looks like he purchased a new company laptop that you're using, and when you're done at the company you'll give up the laptop. (The lesson is to never use personal property for company purposes - or vice versa.)

Comment: Why can't you just reimage your old personal laptop and not put any of the buggy work stuff on it?

Comment: Off topic but you could potentially have a claim against the company for the replacement of your laptop.  But that does not mean that you are entitled to take company property (the new laptop) as compensation.  You would need a lawyer to help with anything like that.  Even if you had written documentation that the new laptop was intended to be compensation, should the company demand it back your safest course of action would be to turn over the laptop and seek legal restitution.  You could end up facing theft charges, and I seen something similar end in that.

Comment: @JoeSTrazzere - I think you overestimate the technical competence of the average judge on the small claims circuit.  But then again I said "POTENTIALLY" and check with a lawyer.  It has not been clarified that the damage was just to the software.  It could be physical damage was done.  That has never been clarified.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere probably cracked software that is riddled with virus is my bet.

Comment: I don't see anything you mention pointing out how it could be your laptop. You were reimbursed for it, so you are not out of pocket.

Comment: Joe back in the day Oracles forms development tools  used to cause blue screen crashes every 10 to 15 min.

Answer (score 15):

This is the problem with verbal agreements: everybody involved understands it differently and there's no record to consult.

In this case, because you used the company credit card for the purchase, you are probably out of luck.  Your best approach to correcting the problem will be through negotiation, not legal appeals.  "Hey boss, when you said you'd replace my personal property that was damaged because of work, I thought you meant the new machine would be mine too.  What can we do to make this right?  Do you need me to pay some part of the cost since it's a newer, better machine?"

In the future, if personal property is damaged on the job it is much better for you to seek reimbursement for your expenses, rather than having the company pay them directly.  That way it's clearer, and if they reimburse you via your paycheck it may even generate a specific line-item for your records.

All that said, it sounds like the company provided you a machine that you decided you didn't want to use.  If that happens again, you should discuss the problem with them up front before resorting to the use of personal property.  If you can avoid putting yourself in the position of having to use your own property, you can avoid this class of problems.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, especially for hardware, but you can't always avoid it.  For example, I bought my own office chair because I found the standard-issue ones in our office to be ergonomically unsuitable; I could have petitioned for them to evaluate and buy me one, but it was easier for me to just go shopping and pay for it.  I made sure they knew that it's personal property (and I'll take it when I leave), and it has a suitable sticker on it now.

Comment: I'm using my own mouse/keyboard for similar reasons. And whiteboard, for that matter. But I've got "Personal property of enderland" on all of them in permanent marker...

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've done the same.  While I agree with Joe that it's a suboptimal situation, when the choices boil down to spending a few hundred dollars on a chair that allows you to work comfortably or spending a few hundred dollars on chiropractory in an attempt to mitigate the effects of sitting in a bad chair for 40 hours/week, it becomes painfully apparent that standing on principles is no more than cutting off your nose to spite your face.

Answer (score 2):

OK, unless it's a Mac PowerBook, laptops are incredibly cheap.  $500 gets you a really decent machine these days, if you watch the store specials.

- First, get your original one working, ASAP, and use it for school. 
  You're right back to where you started from.  Put in a new hard
  drive, re-install the OS (If it's Windows, your license key is on a
  sticker, probably on the bottom of the machine) and get that thing
  working again.
- Second, stop using the other laptop for school.  Your boss reneged on
  the agreement, so the new laptop is effectively the company's, now.  Get everything for school *OFF* of that PC.  Use DropBox, GoogleDrive, or whatever to keep your stuff "handy."
- Third, realize your mistake in ever using your own machine for your
  employer.  If their machines are problems, then get a virtualized
  machine running inside of theirs (VMWare Workstation or Microsoft Virtual
  PC), and use that for your work.  *NEVER* put your own software on it.
- Fourth, realize how lucky you are to just lose a laptop to this
  company.  From this day forward, never take anything to work you
  can't walk away from.  Pictures?  Bring in copies.  Personal
  knickknacks?  Better be cheap and have no sentimental value. 
  Personal computer - absolutely never.  Leave it locked in your car or
  better yet, leave it at home and run LogMeIn to reach it from work if
  you have to.
- Fifth, and I hate to say this:  Unless you change yourself, this will not be the last time an
  employer steals from you.  They are the business equivalent of an
  abusive spouse.  Abusive employers require employees that don't stand
  up for themselves to "get away with it."  Stop being that employee. 
  They treat you like dirt and make you feel like you're not worth
  working anywhere else.  Finish your degree and get happy at your
  "Real" job as fast as you can.  Don't ever look back on this job.

Comment: *"this will not be the last time an employer steals from you."* Care to explain this? How exactly did the employer steal in this case?

Comment: The employer hasn't stolen from him. He was reimbursed for purchasing a laptop. It doesn't mean he automatically owns it.

Comment: $500 for a nice machine depends on the country you are in. If Liz is in the US, that's alright, but if she's in Mexico it may be not that cheap, and in Brazil that wouldn't even buy any machine whatsoever.

Comment: @jmac - He used personal property for work, and that property was damaged by using it for work.  That property was not repaired or replaced by his employer.  That's theft where I come from.  You may see it differently.

Comment: @Renan - True enough.  The colloquialisms used in the original story suggest Liz is at least originally from the U.S., and Liz is an English name.  Assumptions were made.

Comment: @Wesley, look at the [wikipedia article on theft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theft). Their summary: *"theft is the taking of another person's property without that person's permission or consent with the intent to deprive the rightful owner of it."* The company did not take any property period, nor did it have intent to deprive the owner of that property. There is nothing that indicates the asker was forced to use a personal computer for work, nor that there was any expectation that this would break said computer. Again, what makes this theft?

Comment: (while I get a delightful image when thinking of an employer twisting his mustache saying, *"Now for my next evil scheme, I will have work software installed on my employee's personal computer, and when it breaks the computer I will refuse to reimburse it and reap huge profits!"*, I don't think it's a very plausible scenario -- there are probably far more employees trying to con their employers in to reimbursing them for fraudulent 'work-related' expenses than vice versa)

Comment: @jmac - perhaps.  But employers are people just like anyone else, and those that expect others to provide benefit and resources without compensation are thieves, just like the brother-in-law who "borrows" money from you and never repays it.  They don't think of themselves as thieves.  No one believes themselves to be evil.  It's when you don't honor your agreements and you delude yourself into believing you have every right to take things from others without honoring your side of the bargain that you become evil.  The employer will never see himself as having done anything wrong, but he is.

Comment: @jmac - If you promise to buy someone a thing, buy that thing, and then take it back, that is theft.  It was Liz's property under the agreement, and then she was "strong-armed" out of it by the employer, IMO under the implicit threat of losing her job.  Sorry - spin it any way you want, but this is theft.  This where legalities part ways with morals and ethics, true, but this is theft.

Comment: @Wesley, whether we call it theft, or just poor manners is really irrelevant. It's a bad thing to do. My point here is that there is no indication that the employer requested the asker to use their computer for work-related activities, so assuming that there was an agreement when it may have been the choice of the asker dramatically changes the responsibility of the employer. If I decide to bring in my own chair to the office, and it breaks, the employer is not obligated to buy me one. If they tell me I need to buy my own chair, that is a separate story. Don't make assumptions.

Comment: @jmac - But if you bring your own chair to the office, and the employer breaks it, but buys you a new chair to replace it, then they have agreed to take responsibility.  Now, is that new chair yours or theirs?  You're only incorporating half of the events into your scenario.  Liz is right - her employer is a jerk.  You're trying to rationalize the employer stealing from her.  Yes, Liz made a poor choice in using her own machine for work, but that doesn't mean it's open season on her.  It certainly doesn't mean the employer can "Take it back" just because he changed his mind.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11389/discussion-between-jmac-and-wesley-long)